# "I have/am" - what are other short ways to not repeat this in a cover letter?

Tags: letter, resume, phrasing, cover-letter

I use the GIS/Programing ones extensively.

For a cover letter, what are ways that you can avoid repeating

> I have done ....
>   I have experience with ...
>   I am experienced in...
>   ...

Comment: This question is asking for a list, something that doesn't work well with Stack Exchange sites. (How will you pick the answer? How are people expected to vote?) Could you please rewrite to tell us what you are looking for, as opposed to what you're trying to avoid? Otherwise we'll have to close.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are actually quite a few options, many of which come naturally when you're not forced to consciously write formally.

You can change the verb into an –ing:

> "Having done freelance for 8 years, I..."
>
> "Choosing to work from home has..."

or in some cases turn the verb into the subject or your sentence.

> "Experience with Java has helped..."

This gives it an assertive feel, as does any other form of eliminating personal pronouns. Though one should include some personal pronouns for fear one begins to sound impersonal. :)

You can also add introductory phrases or prepositional phrases to the beginnings of your sentences:

> "In my extensive set of skills, I..."
>
> "With my passion for social media, ..."

If you're currently writing the cover letter, it might be best to get all your thoughts and strengths down first before editing for repetition and word choice.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of saying, "I have experience with X," consider describing what you did with X.  "I created a global meteor defense system using Java and Arduino."